# send email with image from mobile using smtp client

Tags: smtpclient

I am trying to send an email with image from mobile web using smtp client.
If the image is a pdf file it is works good, but when i am trying to add an image from the gallery it is shows a server error.

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
            string name = context.Request.Form["name"];
            string email = context.Request.Form["email"];
            string msg = context.Request.Form["msg"];

             for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
              {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                string fname;
                //string fname = context.Request.Form["str"].ToString();
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                {
                    string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' 
                 });
                    fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    fname = file.FileName;
                }
                fname = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/"), fname);

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("name@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add("name@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "new order";
                mail.Body =msg;

                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.InputStream,file.FileName));
                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("name@gmail.com","password");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            }  
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the error

Comment: @person It shows "Internal Server error"